# Bloquear ou liberar um controller de acordo com alguma condição

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho um controller que só deve ser acessado se um atributo na minha tabela for "true". Há alguma maneira de na hora que o usuario clicar no tal link, verificar se o atributo é true, e só então liberar o acesso?

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi:
Vc quer que quando o usuário clicar em um link o sistema verifique se o atributo da sua table é true e se for leva para outra página, isso?

Comment: Sim. Caso não seja, exiba uma mensagem de erro!

Comment: Deixa eu explicar melhor. Eu tenho uma table chamada publicações, quando o usuario posta uma publicação no site, ela é inserida como false, pois não foi validada. Após a validação dessa publicação, o usuario poderá adicionar capítulos a ela e etc. Eu quero que enquanto a publicação estiver como false, o usuario não seja capaz de acessar o controller que o permite adicionar capítulos.

Comment: Quando vc diz table é tabela do banco de dados ou tabela em html da view?

Comment: No banco mesmo.

Comment: Nesse caso é uma simples verificação que vc faz no seu banco através do controller. Vc pode fazer isso via ajax ou modo convencional mesmo.
Basta no seu controller vc criar um método que dado o id do usuário retorne o valor do atributo que vc quer checar, se o valor for true vc continua se não vc manda um response pra view com a exceção desejada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode deixar o usuário acessar o *Controller* sem problemas. Apenas crie dentro uma regra de negócio que não o permita continuar:

```cs
public ActionResult AdicionarCapitulos(int id)
{
    var publicacao = contexto.Publicacoes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    if (!publicacao.Validada) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Publicação ainda não validada. Não é permitido a edição.");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Publicacoes");
    }

    // Coloque aqui o resto da lógica
}
```